# Bash string transformation

Tags: bash

Could you please help me get from

```
inputs='["some string", "BBB", "CCC", "something else"]'
```

to

```
inputs=( "some string" "BBB" "CCC" "something else" )
```

using some bash code?

Thank you.

Later Edit:
The result should be a bash array. as per solutions provided by @james and @Francois, they create just a string.

Any ideas?
Thanks again.

Comment: So, did you try anything?

Comment: like: `echo $inputs | sed -e "s/\[/( /" -e "s/\]/ )/"` ?

Comment: The solutions given will badly break in many cases. Are you actually trying to parse json?

Comment: not a json... the string `inputs='["some string", "BBB", "CCC", "something else"]'` comes as a result from a ruby code and what I need is to transform that string into a bash array.

Comment: can't you modify the ruby script so that it outputs the array in a more parsable format? (e.g., one string per line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed "s/\[/( /; s/]/ )/; s/[',]//g" foo
inputs=( "some string" "BBB" "CCC" "something else" )
```

First replace `\[` with `(`, `]` with `)` and then `'` and `,` with nuthin'.

Comment: The problem is now solved, but there's another. The resulted string is not an array anymore. If I try to make it an array with: `IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$inputs"` I get as a result more elements as each space declares a new element. Any ideeas?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a variable called `inputs` that contains `["some string", "BBB", "CCC", "something else"]`, then you can use `jq` and `mapfile`:

```
$ mapfile -t inputs < <(jq -r '.[]' <<< "$inputs")
$ printf '<%s>' "${inputs[@]}"
<some string><BBB><CCC><something else>
```

Comment: that line was just to show that spaces is respected. After running the first command (`mapfile`) an array called `inputs` will exists.

Comment: I'm stupid and you're right. Thank you very much. Is there any other way to do that without `jq`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple substitution using `sed`

```
inputs=$(echo $inputs | sed -e "s/\[/( /" -e "s/\]/ )/" -e "s/,//g")
```

(last expression deletes the commas, overlooked it in the first attempt)

Comment: I got it. Thank you guys! Jean-Francois, I'll use your solution. I really appreciate!

Comment: @GabrielEnache this doesn't delete the commas though... is that okay or do you mean you were able to modify the solution to your needs?

Comment: @Sundeep: added a last expression: overlooked it (as the OP did :)). Thx.